# Python os.geteuid() for windows

Tags: python, windows, unix, celery

I saw that os.geteuid() is only available for unix, how to replace its usage in windows. I needed this because celery is using the function and for celery to run in windows I need this function alternative for windows. Please do help.

Comment: Celery do not use `os.geteuid` in windows. What exactly do you want to implement?

Comment: @alko :In celery 3.1.5 os.geteuid() is being used. The fix is done and this friday they said they are going to release the new version of 3.1.6 with the fix. Currently the fix is in development version which can be used, i.e. install from master branch.

Answer (score 0):

User id in Windows? I'm not sure [getpass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) is what you want.

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()

>>> 'HelloWorld'
```

But be careful, the function is return values of various **environment variables**.

Environment variable can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find user-information for a given process then you can try something like this:

```
import wmi
def GetUserInfoForProcess(processName):
    _wmi = wmi.WMI()
    for proc in _wmi.Win32_Process(Description=processName):
        (domain, unknown, user) = proc.GetOwner()
        # (blah, userSid) = proc.GetOwnerSid()
        return user

    return None

    # Usage
GetUserInfoForProcess("explorer.exe")
```

You can find wmi module here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/ and http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html